# Sending email fails as non-object specifiying error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have run into a little problem with emailing using the following code

```
    $username=$p['register_name'];   
    $email=$p['register_email'];
    $activation=md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
    $password=md5($p['register_password']);

    $member_data=array
    (
        'name'=> $username,
        'email'=> $email,
        'pass'=> $password,
        'activation' => $activation
    );

    $bSuccess=$this->blog->insert_member($member_data);
    if($bSuccess)
    {
        $msg="Click the following URL to activate your account :<br/>
                http://myforums.com/activation.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&key=".$activation;
        $from="valid_email@myforum.com";
        $this->email->from($from, 'Forums Administrator');      
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject("Account activation");
        $this->email->message($msg);
        if(!$this->email->send())
        {
            echo "Unable to send activation email";   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "An activation link has been sent to your ".$email.".Follow that link to activate your account";
        }
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

the runtime error is

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$email
>
> Filename: forums/login.php
>
> Line Number: 20
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function from() on a non-object in
>   login.php on line 20

I think I have defined 'email' variable from the start. This is strange/

**UPDATE**
I loaded the email library in the constructor and everything then works fine
Still, a new error shows up as follows,

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 553 5.5.4
>   ... Real domain name required for sender address
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1553

Answer (score 2):

`$this->email` looks like a helper that you need to load first.  Would be nice to see the entire file/function

`$this->load->library('email');` needs to be defined before you can use $this->email->from

and thenext answer is

valid_email@myforum.com

is not a valid email address.  I am assuming that myforum.com does not reverse resolve DNS wise and the server you are using is reverse resolving DNS.

Comment: Thank you I updated my post please help me with the new error

Comment: ok, so you're new.  You usually don't ask a new question in the same question block, you start a new question.  That said I gave you the answer, please give my answer the gold checkmark since I did solve your first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the email library?

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

The error is because the $email property of $this (i'm assuming this is the code for the controller) isn't set, and that probably is because the library isn't loaded.

See the example in the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html).

Comment: I think you should open another question for that problem, but i'm not sure... anyway. It seems like a server problem. Look [this](http://3xsp.blogspot.com/2011/05/real-domain-name-required-for-sender.html) or [this](http://selliott.org/node/40).